# Filter products by price

Tags: php, sql, filter

I am trying to filter product by price but ran into a problem with special price.
If the special price is applicable in product than below query is showing random results.

```
"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ((price >= ".(int)$min_price." AND price <= ".(int)$max_price." AND ('".date('Y-m-d')."' NOT BETWEEN special_price_startdate AND special_price_enddate OR special_price_startdate = NULL OR special_price_enddate= NULL)) OR (('".date('Y-m-d')."' BETWEEN special_price_startdate AND special_price_enddate AND special_price_startdate IS NOT NULL AND special_price_enddate IS NOT NULL) AND special_price >= ".(int)$min_price." AND special_price <= ".(int)$max_price.")) AND isactive = 1 AND isdeleted = 0 ORDER BY created DESC, productid DESC LIMIT ".(($page-1)*$perpage).",".$perpage;
```

Comment: It would make it easier to help if you could tell us what results you expect and what you actually get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query does exactly what it should do according to its syntax: if special price is applicable and special price is between set limit, it returns the row. Otherwise, if the special price is not applicable and regular price is between the set limits it returns the row:

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `special_price_startdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `special_price_enddate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `isactive` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isdeleted` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `special_price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Query adjusted for PHP inputs:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tablename
 WHERE     (   (    price >= 99
                AND price <= 999
                AND (   '2017-04-21' NOT BETWEEN special_price_startdate
                                             AND special_price_enddate
                     OR special_price_startdate = NULL
                     OR special_price_enddate = NULL))
            OR (    (    '2017-04-21' BETWEEN special_price_startdate
                                          AND special_price_enddate
                     AND special_price_startdate IS NOT NULL
                     AND special_price_enddate IS NOT NULL)
                AND special_price >= 99
                AND special_price <= 999))
       AND isactive = 1
       AND isdeleted = 0
/*ORDER BY created DESC, productid DESC*/
 LIMIT 10;
```

Insert seed data:

```
INSERT INTO `tablename` values
(1, 120, '2017-04-20', '2017-04-22', 1, 0, 125), 
(2, 125, '2017-04-27', '2017-04-28', 1, 0, 125), 
(3, 120, '2017-04-20', '2017-04-22', 1, 0, 50), 
(4, 50, '2017-04-27', '2017-04-28', 1, 0, 125)
```

Output:

```
1   120 4/20/2017 12:00:00 AM   4/22/2017 12:00:00 AM   1   0   125
2   125 4/27/2017 12:00:00 AM   4/28/2017 12:00:00 AM   1   0   125
```